# In App bundle - dynamic feature module classes not found exception

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error. Can anyone help me out?

```
 Process: com.pack.demo_for_on_demand_assetdb_download, PID: 531
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.pack.demo_for_on_demand_assetdb_download/com.pack.englishassetdb.EnglishDbMainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pack.englishassetdb.EnglishDbMainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pack.demo_for_on_demand_assetdb_download-fK0J7dSHiC_ABCsQi7hPhA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pack.demo_for_on_demand_assetdb_download-fK0J7dSHiC_ABCsQi7hPhA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
```